# How to set number of rows to 5 in interactive report in oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created an Interactive report in Oracle Apex. Maximum rows per page selected as 50.So currently I have options 1,5,10,15,20,25,30,50,  to select number of rows from UI. By default 50 rows are loading. I need to set default count to 5.Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

- run the report
- go to the "Actions" menu

  - "Format"

    - "Rows per page" - set it to 5
- "Actions" menu again

  - "Report"

    - "Save report" - save it as **Default report settings**

That's all.